# CALABASH - cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)

Tags: android, ruby, installation, calabash

I'm trying to run my calabash test on my new machine (Mac OS 10.10.1) but when I run the command I have this output:

```
cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/Users/ptv618/Documents/cardapp_ui_tests/features/support/env.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:95:in `load'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:95:in `load_code_file'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:180:in `load_file'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:83:in `block in load_files!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in `load_files!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:184:in `load_step_definitions'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:42:in `run!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:47:in `execute!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/bin/cucumber:13:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/bin/cucumber:23:in `load'
/usr/bin/cucumber:23:in `<main>'
```

Can anyone help me? I think that is because of something related with the configuration because I could run this test before.

I am using Ruby 2.0.0.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have `bundler` installed? Do you use `rvm` or `rbenv`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you are using Apple's system ruby which requires `sudo` to install gems.  I might be wrong about this.  Can you update your question with the exact command you are trying to execute?

The calabash maintainers recommend using a managed ruby environment like rbenv or ruby. [1]  If a manage ruby is not your style, you can override the `GEM_HOME` and `GEM_PATH` [2]

- [1] https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/wiki/B2-Updating-your-run-loop-version
- [2] http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/calabash/osx-installation/